# Include path problems installing PEAR/PHPUnit

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, pear

I'm following this http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/page/install-pear-phpunit-xdebug-on-macosx-snow-leopard to install PEAR/PHPUnit. I'm having trouble with the include paths.

Some background info:

```
Farooqs-MacBook-Pro:bin fyousuf$ which php
/usr/bin/php

Farooqs-MacBook-Pro:bin fyousuf$ which pear
/usr/local/bin/pear

Farooqs-MacBook-Pro:bin fyousuf$ which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

I think the part where I'm messing up is "Update PHP include path" in the link I posted above.

This is what is in my php.ini file:

```
    ; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
    ;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
    include_path = ”/usr/local/bin/PEAR:/php/includes”
    ;
    ; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
    ;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
    include_path = ”/usr/local/bin/PEAR:/php/includes”
    ;
    ; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
    ; http://php.net/include-path`
```

When I try to run a Selenium test using phpunit I get this error:

```
   phpunit functions.php

   PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such            
   file or directory in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php'         
   (include_path='”/usr/local/bin/PEAR:/php/includes”') in       
   /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
```

New Edits:

I have PHPUnit installed:

Farooqs-MacBook-Pro:echo360-5.0 fyousuf$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.7.27
install failed

But when I type phpunit in terminal I get the same error as before:

PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/PEAR:/php/includes') in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

Comment: For those Googlers who land here because they need to know the path to Pear's PHP files: The best approach is to simply execute (on the command line): `pear config-get php_dir`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message states that PHPUnit is located in this pear directory:

```
/usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit
```

This should transform into this path to be added to the include_path setting:

```
/usr/local/pear/share/pear
```

You currently defined `/usr/local/bin/PEAR`, which looks weird. Especially since the install directions state that it should be `/usr/local/PEAR`, but this depends on how PEAR was actually installed.

Comment: I have PHPUnit installed:

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter by mistake :) Thanks for the answer, it helped to fix the problem.

Comment: Originally I had this in my include_path in /etc/php.ini:

`include_path = ".:/usr/local/PEAR:/php/includes"`

But I had to change it to this to fix the problem:

`include_path = ".:/usr/local/PEAR:/usr/local/pear/share/pear:/php/includes"`

Comment: You should always try and keep the include path as short as possible. Have you made sure the path `/usr/local/PEAR` exists on your system? If not, remove that part - it isn't useful. It will only cost performance when including files.